# SonicWALL - VPN no LAN conneciton

Tags: vpn, lan, sonicwall, policing

Hey guys I have a Problem.

I have no idea why but when I'm connected via VPN I'm not albe to connect to the LAN Servers in our Network. I can surf through the internet with the VPN but I'm not even able to Ping them... It's not a site to site VPN just normal Client To Network.

Did I forgot something? Do you need further information?

1st Pic VPN -> LAN
2nd Pic LAN -> VPN

[image: VPN -> LAN Policies]
[image: LAN -> VPN Policies]

```
    netstat -r
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.37.1       UGSc           26        0     en1
80.150.XXX.4       192.168.37.1       UGHS            0        0     en1
127                localhost          UCS             0        0     lo0
localhost          localhost          UH             14 35760176     lo0
169.254            link#5             UCS             0        0     en1
192.168.0.1        192.168.5.3        UH              1        2    ppp0
192.168.5          ppp0               USc             0        0    ppp0
192.168.37         link#5             UCS             1        0     en1
192.168.37.1       68:7f:74:1:d1:5d   UHLWIir        33      173     en1   1162
ersatzbook         localhost          UHS             0       25     lo0
```

[image: NatPolicy]

This is the VPN Access:

[image: VPN Access]

And here we can See the Address Object which is defined in the Firewall.

[image: Address Object]

After all that there are no changes in the connection to the LAN server. But still I'm not able to connect to them.

Comment: are you using ssl or vpn client to connect vpn?

Comment: I'm just using normal VPN with PreSharedKey, Username and Password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check if your client has correct routes. Asumming windows, execute *route print* in cmd. You should see a line containing a route for your LAN throught your VPN interface. Something like

192.168.10.0 (your lan) 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.200 (your VPN asigned IP)

Does this route exist on your client routing table?

In case not, your SonicWall fw is not passing correct network proposals in one of the phases of IPSec negotiation. There are an option where you can specify what networks can be accesible from your remote client.

This VPN allowed networks are not in the firewall rules, they are located in a tab called VPN Access in the user config, i mean the user you configured for VPN access. Check [this URL](https://support.software.dell.com/kb/sw7507) for screenshots and a further explanation.

Comment: as above look at the Topic.

Comment: I am in the LAN but i have no idea why I'm not able to ping for example Server 192.168.0.9

Comment: I am able to ping the SonicWALL on 192.168.0.1

Comment: Which is the IP assigned to your remote client? Maybe 192.168.5.3?

Comment: Yeah that's the VPN-IP I got when I'm in the network

Comment: And, which IP network is the remote LAN you are trying to access?

Comment: I'm connected to 192.168.0.1 intranet but I'm not able to Ping other IP-addresses of the network like 192.168.0.9 and thats what i need.

Comment: Well, as I pointed out in the main post, you are NOT routing your LAN 192.168.0.0/24 throught your VPN connection. You are routing just the IP 192.168.0.1. IP 192.168.0.2-254 are being routed over your default internet connecction.

This happens because your Sonicwall is not passing correct routes to the remote client. If you edit your user in sonicwall (the one used for VPN)  you'll find a tab called "VPN Access". You have to add an object containing your LAN network "192.168.0.0/24". If you do this and reconnect your VLAN, you should see a new route 192.168.0 192.168.5.3 and it should work

Comment: KorXo I added these Policy into my VPN Username
Look at the Topic I aded 2 Screenshots

Comment: I suggest you drop the tunnel and reconnect and check if routes are been passsing to the remote client. If not routes are passed, you have the problem in the establishing tunnel. To check this theory, add a static route in your pc that route 192.168.0.0/24 network throught your interface ppp0 with ip 192.168.5.3

Focus on this troubleeshooting and good luck ;)

Comment: Uh... well easy to say. But I'm not so good with Mac OSX and Network. Thats the reason why I'm asking here ^^

Comment: Awww man.... I'm so ****. I found the issue... There was/is a setting in the VPN Client from MacOSX to put every network connection through the VPN... Now it routes everything through the VPN and I'm able to Ping and SSH the Server in LAN and DMZ. Arigatou Gozaimasu! Thanks Alot!

Answer (score 0):

Awww man.... I'm so ****. I found the issue... There was/is a setting in the VPN Client from MacOSX to put every network connection through the VPN... Now it routes everything through the VPN and I'm able to Ping and SSH the Server in LAN and DMZ. Arigatou Gozaimasu! Thanks Alot Every One!